# triple sql inner joins or using python to get the same data using mongodb library?

Tags: python, mongodb, join, nested, nested-loops

I have to make more than two sql inner joins to get specific data from MongoDB database. on the other hand, I can get the same data using mysql.connector python library and trying to avoid damn nested loop (ex: using map function). what is the best way for doing so ? and ,why ? 
is there better alternative way ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas query if all your script is python?
its effectively passing a string that resembles an sql query

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html